# What is the difference between signing Certificate and Encryption Certificate?

Tags: key, public, digital-certificate, infrastructure

What is the difference between between signing certificate and encryption certificate?

I see that signing certificate cannot be used for encrypting the data only encryption certificate. What is the technical difference? Does both have public key and private or only encryption cert will have PP key?

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 3):

Even this is an old thread, I've just been struggling with those certificate,encryt/decrypt concepts, put two my cents on this, the short one:

- Signing Certificate and Encyption Certificate use different certifiate scheme, and main difference (to me)is: Signing Certificate set private key as encyption key and public key as decryption key, where encryption certicate totally in opposite.

The long one:

- Both the certificates use Asymmetric encryption algorithm, which have two keys, the one used to encypt the message and the another to decypt the message, and I don't think the encyption/dectytion key can be used in dual-direction, which means given a pair of two keys, there is and only one can be used as encyption key and another used as dectyption key.
- Signing process: firstly use hash algorithm to calculate a message hash, and then use Signer's certificate **private key to encypt** the hash, and put the message + encypted hash + Signer's certifiate(include public key) togother, then send out the world, later the encypted hash can use **signer's certificate public key to decrypt**.
- Encytion process: usually the sender shall use **receiver's certificate's public key to encypt** the message, and when the message received, the receiver uses its certificate **private key to decypt** the message.
- Signing process typically not toward a specific endpoint, it can be self-proven, and be sent anywhere, where the encyption process usually has two endpoints, they use each other's public key to encyt the data for comunicating...

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is the value of the purpose field in the certificate. The issuer of the certificate chooses for what purpose the certificate is created.

Comment: I acknowledge your answer with thanks.
But how does the value or attribute limits the functionality of the certificate? Encyrption certificate will not be used for signing and siging for encryption? when we have both public key and private in both certs how will it be limited?

Comment: The certificate says what it can be used for. The applications doing the signing and verifying check the purpose field. If you wrote your own tool chain you could ignore that field --- but would give errors for anyone else. There is nothing in the underlying signing algorithm that is changed by the purpose (which converts a byte stream into another array of bytes).

Answer (score 0):

A certificate contains only the public certificate. Nothing can stop you from using the private *key* for whatever things you want to do with it.

As said before, a certificate is for the other party to deal with - after you have signed or encrypted something, the other party needs to make the decision if it is happy with it. It then checks the certificate and its flags to make sure it could be used for the operation, under the policy set for the other party.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the "key usage" fields in the certificates, some key pairs use algorithms that can only do signing or encryption (key exchange). For example, DH and DSA. RSA is good for both so technically you can do whatever you want. But as other answers pointed out, the code that verifies your signature will probably reject it because the certificate was used for wrong purpose.